# javascript function make animate div css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to make a div animate `onmouseover`, but it is not working

Here is my javascript that I used the `.style.animation` for Internet Explorer and Firefox,  and the `.style.webkitanimation` for chrome:

```
function emailhelp() { 

  document.getElementById('help-text').innerHTML = 'Enter you&acute;re email';
  document.getElementById('help-box').style.animation ='myfirst 5s;';
  document.getElementById('help-box').style.webkitanimation ='myfirst 5s;';

}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@keyframes myfirst
{
  from {background-color:#00304c;}
  to {background-color:yellow;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
  from {background-color:#00304c;}
  to {background-color:yellow;}
}
#help-box {
 position: fixed;
 top: 82px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: 289px;
 font-size: 12px;
 background-color: #00304c;
 height: 32px;
 width: 250px;
 line-height: 32px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<input class="user-input" name="" type="text" value="email" onmouseover="emailhelp()" onmouseout="helphide()" onfocus="if(this.value == 'email') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'email'; }" onmouseover="emailhelp()" onmouseout="helphide()" />
```

Comment: `jQuery.animate(/*css property*/)` is easyest way to animate div in JS

Comment: as in 'function emailhelp() {

  document.getElementById('help-text').innerHTML = 'Enter you&acute;re email';
   
 jQuery.animate('myfirst 5s;')
 
   
  
}'

Comment: No.
Something like this :
`jQuery('help-text').animate('color':'yellow')`
see the documentation of jQuery for more infos :)

Comment: Do you have any html that goes with your help function?

Comment: @KLK Why do you involve jQuery suddenly? And who says using jQuery is the easiest way to animate things? This question is clearly about CSS animations and triggering them via javascript.

Comment: I prefer JS and jQuery instead CSS animations ^^' Sorry

Comment: btw it's `your` email, not `you're (you are)` email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capitalize the property (at least for webkit):

```
document.getElementById('help-box').style.WebkitAnimation ='myfirst 5s';
```

For FF, your code should be OK:

```
document.getElementById('help-box').style.animation ='myfirst 5s';
```

**Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E4vSx/**

Comment: another problem it only does animates once

Comment: @ConnorCushionMulhall if you have another question, please create a new post instead of adding comments.

Comment: glad nobody pointed out my massive grammatical error in my code

Answer (score 0):

This is where I got to for you before you chose another answer.

Use of inline javascript is considered bad practice.

```
<input class="user-input" name="" type="text" value="email" />
<div id="help-box">
    <div id="help-text"></div>
</div>

var input = document.getElementsByClassName("user-input")[0];
var helpBox = document.getElementById("help-box");
var helptext = document.getElementById("help-text");

helpBox.style.visibility = "hidden";

function emailhelp() {
    helpBox.style.visibility = "visible";

    helptext.textContent = "Enter your email";

    helptext.style.WebkitAnimation = "myfirst 5s";
    helptext.style.animation = "myfirst 5s";
}

function helphide() {
    helpBox.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function focus(evt) {
    if (evt.target.value === "email") {
        evt.target.value = "";
    }
}

function blur(evt) {
    if (evt.target.value === "") {
        evt.target.value = "email";
    }
}

input.addEventListener("mouseover", emailhelp, false);
input.addEventListener("mouseout", helphide, false);
input.addEventListener("focus", focus, false);
input.addEventListener("blur", blur, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/jtAKa/)